# Attach debugger to local IIS without administrator permission

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, iis-10

To be able to attach to `w3wp.exe` Visual Studio wants to have elevated permissions so I either have to start VS as admin or add my local user to the `Administrators` group. Is there any other way, another group etc, to be able to attach to `w3wp.exe` *without* having elevated permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Attach debugger to local IIS without administrator permission

I am afraid you can **NOT** do that without administrator permission.

According to the [ASP.NET Debugging: System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/aspnet-debugging-system-requirements):

> **If you change the ASP.NET worker process to run under your own user
>   account, you do not have to be an Administrator on the server that is
>   running IIS**

And [Using IIS with Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(v=vs.120).aspx#Using%20IIS%20with%20Visual%20Studio):

> Disadvantages of Using IIS as a Development Web Server Using IIS as a
>   development server can require more setup and configuration tasks in
>   order to work with Visual Studio than using IIS Express, including the
>   following:
>
> - **You must run Visual Studio as an administrator in order to work with IIS**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the process under your own user account.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-run-the-worker-process-under-a-user-account

Comment: Have you got it working with IIS 10 and VS2017? I tried to follow the instructions but IIS couldn't start after I added username and password.

Comment: This will still run process in session 0, making debugging without admin impossible.