# Do not have enough privilege on Visual Studio 2019 to attach w3p process on local system?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, attach-to-process

I was trying to attach w3p process to debug on Visual Studio 2019 as Admin User but I am getting error as you do not have enough privilege to attach to process. I checked my Local policies and I don't have rights on Debug Programs.

Is there a way to use Attach to Process without access on this Policy.

Comment: Did you run your VS as administrator and then attach it to process?

Comment: Yes running as an Administrator. Can it be due to some folder level access as well or we need to have access on Debug programs in Local Security  Policy

Comment: If you are not an administrator account, you can try to add your current domain by `Start `-->`Control Panel`-->`Administrative tools`-->`Local Security Policy`-->`Local Policies`-->`User Rights Assignment`-->`Debug programs`. Second, follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/unable-to-attach-to-the-process?view=vs-2019) to change. Third , you can try to move this application to a public folder on your local system to make sure it can access.

Comment: And l am afraid you cannot attach it to process without administrator permission.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51418788/attach-debugger-to-local-iis-without-administrator-permission).

Comment: Thanks Perry. I changed the process to run under my account now which was running under network service by default. I am able to debug now.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use Attach to Process without access on this Policy.

l am afraid that you cannot use Attach to Process without access on the Policy and you can refer the info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51418788/attach-debugger-to-local-iis-without-administrator-permission).

To troubleshoot your issue, you can try these:

**1)** add your current domain by `Start` -->`Control Panel`-->`Administrative tools`-->`Local Security Policy`-->`Local Policies`-->`User Rights Assignment`-->`Debug programs`.

**2)** make sure that `the local security setting` selects **Classic**( `Start` -->`Control Panel`-->`Administrative tools`-->`Local Security Policy`-->`Local Policies`-->`Security Options`-->`User Rights Assignment`-->double-click `Network access: Sharing and security model for local accounts`.)

More info you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/unable-to-attach-to-the-process?view=vs-2019).

**3)** If the w3p process is from shared network, please insure the current account is on the Shared LAN and make sure that your account can access network and this process.

**4)** If the w3p application is on your lcoal system, please move this application to a public folder such as `D disk` not a system disk to make sure it can access.

Hope it could help you.